# How can I attach the user id and role id to the pivot table in laravel using attach function?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, foreign-keys, pivot

`RegisterController.php`

```php
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $role = Role::where('name', 'customer')->first();

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
        ]);

        $user->role()->attach(['user_id' => $user->id, 'role_id' => $role->id]);

        return $user;
    }
```

> On above code segement I am trying to `attach` the `user_id` and `role_id` to the `pivot` table which is named as `role_user` at the time of **User Registration**

`User.php`

```php
public function role()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

> In above code segment is the relationship between `User` and `Role`

The error I am getting.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`deal_ocean`.`role_user`, CONSTRAINT `role_user_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `role_user` (`role_id`, `user_id`) values (5, 5), (4, 5))

**For Reference**: Below is the tables I have created.

```php
         Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(4);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->longText('cartitems')->nullable();
            $table->longText('wishlist')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('discount')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

> Above table is for `users` table.

```php
       Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('display_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> Above table is for `roles` table.

```php
       Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> Above table is for `role_user` table.

Comment: Why do you `$table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(4);` in your user table when you have a separate user_role table for managing the relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

you should not pass user_id for attaching when you use $user-> ...

just pass the role id:

```
$user->role()->attach( $role->id);
```

Answer (score 1):

@ImrulHasan,

Right off the bat, I can see a number of problems.

1. `$user->role()->attach(['user_id' => $user->id, 'role_id' => $role->id]);`

You don't actually have to provide the user id and role id separately, just provide the role id and laravel will take care of the rest.
`$user->role()->attach($role->id);`

2. In you `users` table migration, you are creating a **roles** field which is unnecessary, cause you are defining a many-to-many relationship. So, you can take out that line and the line which is setting the relation with the **roles** table.

After you do all the required changes, it should work fine.

Comment: If I don't use role_id there ... then I dont have to use any foreign key for the role id?

Comment: Yes absolutely, cause your role_user table takes care of that. It already tracks both the user_id and role_id. For more info, please refer to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)